# Calculate the sum of the series (1/(n+1) -log(n+2)+log(n+1))

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to calculate the following sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1} - a_n$$

Where $$a_n = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}- \int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} \, dx$$

I have that $$a_{n+1} - a_n= \dfrac{1}{n+1} - (log(n+2)-log(n+1))$$ but I don't know what else to do, so any help would be very appreciated, thank you!

I found this in wolfram but I don't know how this was obtained:

[image]

Comment: Look at partial sums ($\sum_1^N$) and notice that these are indeed telescopic...

Answer (score 3):

Note that the sum is [telescopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series):
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \left(a_{n+1} - a_n\right)=a_{N}-a_1=
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}- \int_{1}^{N+1} \dfrac{dx}{x}-1+\int_{1}^{2} \dfrac{dx}{x}\\=H_N-\ln(N+1)+\ln(2)-1$$
where $H_N=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}$ is the $N$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). Recall that, as $N$ goes to infinity,
$$H_N=\ln(N)+\gamma +o(1)$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). Can you take it from here?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the euler-mascheroni constant which is close to the number that appears in wolfram. So what follows is to see that ln(N)- ln(N+1) converges to 0?

Comment: @user392559 Yes, and you limit should be $\gamma+\ln(2)-1\approx 0.27036284546$.

Comment: Oh well, thank you! :)